# Dupont grout sealer on vinyl tile OK?

Tags: tile, grout, vinyl-flooring, sealer

Hi I got some Dupont grout sealer for the grout lines around some vinyl tile. Realized the bottle says use for ceramic, porcelain, and stone tile.

Don't know if that means I can't use it on grout if next to vinyl tiles.

Anyone have experience with this?

Doesn't make much sense why the tile type would matter except maybe for cleanup. I remember grouting that tile and the grout was difficult to scrape up off the tile.

Comment: I'd test using left over tile scraps if you have them.  It could damage the finish or "melt" the tile.  Traditionally vinyl tile isn't a tile that uses grout, although I've actually seen the modern exception to that statement.  Proceed with caution, test on something not visible, or better yet left over scrap.

Comment: The vinyl tile I used is specifically groutable.

Comment: Which is why I said what I said.   It might be fine, but groutable vinyl isn't anything common. Proceed with caution. Test on material that won't show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a little test and it seemed fine.

I also called the company that now owns that line of Dupont sealer. They said it was fine to use for vinyl tile, just make sure to wipe it off the tile like you would normally do.